# Best lightweight Ruby IDE for Mac OSX?

Tags: ruby, macos, ide

Anyy recommendations on a IDE to use for the MAC?

I currently use TextMate and its ok. Is tere a ay though for it to auto suggest tags?

For example.. typing pu.. would bring up puts etc.

I also tried RubyMine and Komodo but they are both way to bloated for my liking.

Comment: .... you want a light weight editor that does heavy lifting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try MacVim with this set of plugins: https://github.com/akitaonrails/vimfiles . It`s rather lightweight, supports easy navigation and can be customized to any needs.